# Could not find a valid configuration for WebHook receiver

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, webhooks

I have the world's simplest custom webhook receiver.

**WebApiConfig**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
           ......
           ......
        config.InitializeReceiveCustomWebHooks();          
    }
}
```

**CustomWebHookHandler**

```
namespace API.Webhooks
{
    public class CustomWebHookHandler : WebHookHandler
    {
        public CustomWebHookHandler()
        {
            this.Receiver = CustomWebHookReceiver.ReceiverName;
        }

        public override Task ExecuteAsync(string receiver, WebHookHandlerContext context)
        {
            // Get data from WebHook
            CustomNotifications data = context.GetDataOrDefault<CustomNotifications>();

            //Get data from each notification in this WebHook
            foreach (IDictionary<string, object> notification in data.Notifications)
            {
               // Process data
            }


            return Task.FromResult(true);
        }
    }
}
```

**AppSettings in Web.Config**

```
<appSettings>
 <add key="MS_WebHookReceiverSecret_Custom" value="2345678901234567890123456789012" />
</appSettings>
```

**Postman Request** I am sending is the following

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:50962/api/webhooks/incoming/custom/2345678901234567890123456789012' \
--data-raw 'some random test data'
```

The error I get is the following

> "Could not find a valid configuration for WebHook receiver 'custom'
>   and instance '2345678901234567890123456789012'. The setting must be
>   set to a value between 32 and 128 characters long."

Somewhere I read that it only works with HTTPS, so I deployed the API to Azure and sent the following request also gives exactly the same error

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://<myazure API URI> /api/webhooks/incoming/custom/2345678901234567890123456789012' \
--data-raw 'test data'
```

What am I missing, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone struggling with this, you need to use `GenericJson` instead of `Custom`, so you will be initialising GenricJson as following

```
config.InitializeReceiveGenericJsonWebHooks();
```

Custom Receivers are only for ASP.NET webhooks

Comment: A thousand thank yous. Spent hours looking at a 500 error because I was using custom instead of generic.